# How to use IAM tools such as auth0 to implement user access control in a SaaS product

Tags: auth0, access-control, rbac

Assumptions:

1. My company provides 5 products (cloud-based web applications)
2. I want to build a page for my client’s IT manager to manage the user access rights in his/her company.

Example scenarios that I want to achieve:

1. Client_A allows some users (in the company) to use my product_1, while some other users can not use product_1.
2. Client_A allows some users to use certain features in the product_2, while some other users can not use those specific features (but can use the rest of the features in the product_2)

Can I achieve this by using auth0? (http://auth0.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auth0 access control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002598/auth0-access-control)